# Laravel 2 Folders Conflict on Linux Server

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 4.2 on Linux server. Due to the limitation of php version etc. on Linux server, I copied the whole code from local and put it on live. The problem I'm facing is I want two or three same folders on linux environment, so I can test it differently for different environments.

**Giving example of folders** as:

laravel1

laravel2

**Domains example:**

laravel1.testing-dev.com (pointing to laravel1 folder)

laravel2.testing-dev.com (pointing to laravel2 folder)

What happens is, whenever I restart the server and whichever the URL is hit first, the other URL stars referencing the first hit URL folder. I tried to debug it by using the second folder, and made sure its coming into the folder by echoing the **DIR**, public_path and other related config paths, and they are all showing it as laravel2, but when I debug the $app variable, in some places (whoops.handler and whoops related) it shows me the path of laravel1 folder. But I'm not sure if its only linked to the whoops or something else is making it like this.

I've already played around with clearing the cache, removing the sessions and views, but the problem still exist.

**Server:**

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu 14.04.5)

Both URLs are refering to different folders ie larave1 and laravel2

**Virtual Host Configuration**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName laravel1.testing-dev.com

    Redirect permanent / https://laravel1.testing-dev.com/

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel1/public

    <Directory  "/var/www/html/laravel1/public/">

            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

            AllowOverride All

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName laravel2.testing-dev.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel2/public

    <Directory  "/var/www/html/laravel2/public/">

            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

            AllowOverride All

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what are you using as the http server? and how is that configured for each domain?

Comment: please share your configuration in your question

Comment: no - that's your server version... configuration is something like `<virtualhost>...</virtualhost>`

Comment: Can you please post your both virtualhost code and name of that

Comment: Virtual Host Configuration is updated in the question. Thanks

Comment: @HorusKol any thoughts?

Comment: @dekts any thoughts?